# About enveloping algebras of direct sums

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

This question is imported [from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789784/about-enveloping-algebras-of-direct-sums). It is linked to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142623/could-we-define-the-semi-direct-product-of-two-universal-enveloping-algebras) in the case of semi-direct products.

> **My question** Let us consider a Lie $R$-algebra ($R$ is a commutative ring) written as a (module) direct sum of two of its subalgebras
> $$
> \mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus\mathfrak{g}_2\ (\oplus=\oplus_{R-mod})
> $$
> and the natural mapping
> $$
> \alpha : \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1)\otimes_R\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_2)\to\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})
> $$
> ($\mathfrak{g}_i$ are not necessarily ideals).

> On can check, using generators, that $\alpha$ is onto (and, in some usual cases - see below - one-to-one).

> What is true/known in the general case ?

I put here the explicit construction in case one of the $\mathfrak{g}_i$ is an ideal. The proof goes as follows :

Take it that $\mathfrak{g}_1$ is such.

1. Consider the action $\delta : \mathfrak{g}_2\to \mathfrak{Der}
   (\mathfrak{g}_1)$ by derivations (adjoint representation)

   Extend $\delta$ to $\mathfrak{Der}(\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1))$ as in Bourbaki Lie ch 1 paragraph 2.8 prop 7.

   Extend $\delta$ as a morphism of $R$-algebras $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_2)\to\mathrm{End}(\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1))$ by universal property

   Set a law of $R$-unital associative algebra on $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1)\otimes_R\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_2)$ by 
   $$
   (u_1\otimes u_2).(v_1\otimes v_2)=(u_1\otimes 1)\Big((\delta\otimes\gamma_2)\circ\Delta(u_2)\Big)[v_1\otimes v_2] 
   $$
   where $\gamma_2(m)$ is the multiplication by $m$ on the left within $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_2)$.

**Late edit** For those who know the smash product, formula of point 4 says that 
$$
\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})=\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1)\,\sharp\,
\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_2)
$$
where $\sharp$ stands for the smash product defined by the action of $\mathfrak{g}_2$ by derivations on $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1)$.

Comment: Another fairly trivial case is when both Lie algebras are abelian: the universal enveloping algebra is the symmetric algebra and it follows from the functorial properties of the symmetric algebras that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: You're right (+1). In this case we know how to construct an algebra structure on the tensor product. My hope is that we had such a mechanism in the general case. Any idea ?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88598/u-left-mathfrak-a-right-otimes-u-left-mathfrak-a-cap-mathfrak-b-right-u?rq=1 for the case where $R $ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra.

Comment: If you apply $\text{Hom}(-,A)$ to your map for an $R$-algebra $A$, won't both sides be described by $(f,g) \in \text{Hom}(\mathfrak g_1,A) \times \text{Hom}(\mathfrak g_2,A)$ such that $[f(x),g(y)] = 0$ for all $x,y$?

Comment: @ThomasPoguntke I do not think so (if I understand well) as $\mathfrak{g}_1,\,\mathfrak{g}_2$ do not commute between themselves. The sum $$\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus \mathfrak{g}_2$$ is within the category of $R$-module and then, for  $g_i\in \mathfrak{g}_i$, one has $$[g_1,g_2]=p_1([g_1,g_2])+p_2([g_1,g_2])$$

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought $\alpha$ was supposed to be an isomorphism of algebras, which only makes sense if $\mathfrak g_1$ and $\mathfrak g_2$ commute.

Comment: @ThomasPoguntke No problem ! your "error" gave me an idea (+1) towards the general case.

Comment: @ThomasPoguntke It is point 2.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant (just on the other side of the Yoneda embedding).

Comment: @ThomasPoguntke Don't hesitate to formalize your functorial proof as an answer for a partial result, if all is clear (maybe after interaction) I will be glad to upvote it.

Comment: @ThomasPoguntke [an isomorphism of algebras, which only makes sense if $\mathfrak{g_1}$ and $\mathfrak{g_2}$ commute.]--->Not "only", you have twisted products in some categories. This is exactly this sort of "twisted product" I am looking for in the general case.

Comment: If one of them (say $\mathfrak g_1$) is an ideal, $\alpha$ must be one-to-one: in $\mathcal U(\mathfrak g)$ there is a monomial basis of the form $m_1m_2$ where $m_i$ are monomials from $\mathfrak g_i$, since $x_2x_1=x_1x_2+y_1$ with $x_i,y_i\in\mathfrak g_i$, so that any monomial not of the above form is a sum of a monomial "closer to" the above form and a shorter monomial.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I did the case of semi-direct product as you suggested (a bit delicate, but still works thanks to "extension of derivations" in Bourbaki.

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding my comment as a partial answer, as discussed there; this is a reformulation of point 2 that has been added to the question.

Let $\mathcal L$ be the category of Lie $R$-algebras. Assume that $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak g_1 \oplus \mathfrak g_2$ in $\mathcal L$ (direct sum, i.e. I suppose that they commute). Let $\mathcal C$ be the category of unital $R$-algebras. Then $\alpha$ is an isomorphism in $\mathcal C$, since for every unital $R$-algebra $A$, the map
$$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal L}(\mathfrak g,A) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(U(\mathfrak g),A) \stackrel{\alpha^*}{\to} \text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(U(\mathfrak g_1) \otimes_R U(\mathfrak g_2),A)$$
is bijective (by the Yoneda lemma). This is because the right-hand side is given by all
$$(f_1,f_2) \in \text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(U(\mathfrak g_1),A) \times \text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(U(\mathfrak g_2),A) \mbox{ with } [f_1(x_1),f_2(x_2)]=0 \mbox{ for } x_i \in \mathfrak g_i,$$
that is, all pairs of maps $(f_1,f_2)\!: \mathfrak g_1 \oplus \mathfrak g_2 \to A$ in $\mathcal L$ with $[f_1(x_1),f_2(x_2)]=0$ for all $x_i \in \mathfrak g_i$. Then the inverse of $\alpha^*$ is defined by $(f_1,f_2) \mapsto f_1+f_2$, which is well-defined, since
$$(f_1+f_2)([x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2]) = f_1([x_1,y_1]) + f_2([x_2,y_2]) = [f_1(x_1) + f_2(x_2), f_1(y_1) + f_2(y_2)].$$

Comment: For the hasty reader, I added the assumption "(direct sum, i.e. I suppose that they commute)".

Comment: I've specified the categories, and I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: @ThomasPogunke Well, thank you (+1), let me check (and possibly clarify).

Comment: This is the Yoneda lemma: if $\alpha^*$ is a bijective for all $A \in \mathcal C$, then $\alpha$ is an isomorphism in $\mathcal C$.

Comment: If by one-to-one you mean isomorphism, then yes; the Yoneda lemma holds for any category, including $\mathcal C$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78019/discussion-between-duchamp-gerard-h-e-and-thomas-poguntke).

Answer (score 2):

There are probably not many textbook references for these generalities, but I'd suggest looking at the first chapter of the Bourbaki treatise *Groupes et algebres de Lie* (whose chapters I-IX have been translated into English, possibly from later editions than the 1960 Hermann edition of Chapter I which is at hand).

Keep in mind that the first three sections of this chapter treat very general Lie algebras over a commutative ring (with 1) called $K$.    The universal enveloping algebra of a "product" of two Lie algebras over $K$ is considered in $\S2.2$.     I think this is essentially the same set-up you start with, in which the two Lie subalgebras commute with each other; otherwise I'm not sure what you mean by "direct sum".    Anyway, in this framework it's fairly easy to prove that the universal enveloping algebra of such a product is isomorphic to the product of the two universal enveloping algebras: see their Proposition 2.

Are you asking a more subtle question here?  Semi-direct products are of course more difficult to deal with.

Comment: Yeah, Gérard is asking a subtler question: His direct sum is only a direct sum in the category of $R$-modules.

Answer (score 2):

**Late late edit .-** The answer seems to be yes $\alpha$ is one-to one. I give below the scheme of a **tentative proof** (relying on indexed rewriting) as an answer (to be checked thoroughly).

We first build an arrow
$$
\rho\ :\ T(\mathfrak{g})\to T(\mathfrak{g}_1)\otimes T(\mathfrak{g}_2) 
$$
by straightening the inversions. In order not to confuse strings with numbers, we reindex $\mathfrak{g}_1=\mathfrak{g}_a$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2=\mathfrak{g}_b$ where $a<b$ are two symbols. Using the decomposition in

Bourbaki, Algebra Chapter III § 5.5, one gets
$$
T(\mathfrak{g})=\oplus_{w\in \{a,b\}^*}\,T_w
$$
where $\{a,b\}^*$ is the set of words in the symbols $\{a,b\}$ (the free monoid generated by $\{a,b\}$) i.e. mappings
$$
\{1,\cdots n\}\ni i\mapsto w[i]\in \{a,b\}
$$
($n$ is the length of the word and, if $n=0$, one gets the empty word i.e. the unit of the free monoid).
For each word having an inversion at place "$i$" i.e. $w=p\,ba\,s$ where $|p|=i-1$, we have the rewrite rule
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&&r_{w,i}(g_{w[1]}\otimes\ldots \otimes g_b\otimes g_a\otimes\ldots g_{w[n]})=\cr
&&g_{w[1]}\otimes\ldots \otimes [g_b,g_a]_1\otimes\ldots g_{w[n]}+\cr
&&g_{w[1]}\otimes\ldots \otimes [g_b,g_a]_2\otimes\ldots g_{w[n]}+\cr
&&g_{w[1]}\otimes\ldots \otimes g_a\otimes g_b\otimes\ldots g_{w[n]}\cr
&& \in T_{p\,a\,s}\oplus T_{p\,b\,s}\oplus T_{p\,ab\,s} 
\end{eqnarray}
$$
(where $[g,h]_i:=p_i([g,h])$, $p_i$ being the projector on the summands of the decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus\mathfrak{g}_2$) if the indexing word has no inversion at place ``$i$'', $r_{w,i}$ acts trivially (as identity). It is not difficult to check that this system (as usual $r_{w,i}$ is extended to $T(\mathfrak{g})$ by identity to other summands) is confluent (as, if there are two inversions, the indexing word must be of the form
$w=p\,ba\,u\,ba\,s$) and noetherian (as the rules reduce either length or number of inversions). So, the linear map $\rho$ which sends any tensor to its normal form

1. is a projector

   its image is $\oplus_{w\in \{a,b\}^*_{irr}}\,T_w=T(\mathfrak{g}_1)\otimes T(\mathfrak{g}_2)$ 
   ($\{a,b\}^*_{irr}$ being the set of words without inversion i.e. $a^*b^*=\{a^pb^q\}_{p,q\geq 0}$)

   its kernel is the submodule generated by the differences $t-r_{w,i}(t)$

   due to the rewriting properties, one has 
   $$
   \rho(u\otimes \rho(v)\otimes w)=\rho(u\otimes v\otimes w)
   $$

From now on, we return to the original labeling $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus\mathfrak{g}_2$.

Restricting $\rho$ to its image, we get a surjection (still called $\rho$ here)
$$
\rho\ :\ T(\mathfrak{g}) \rightarrow T(\mathfrak{g}_1)\otimes T(\mathfrak{g}_2)
$$
and the factor embedding
$$
j\ :\ T(\mathfrak{g}_1)\otimes T(\mathfrak{g}_2)\hookrightarrow T(\mathfrak{g})   
$$
is a section of it. Together with point (4) above, this suffices to prove that there exists a (unique) law of algebra (associative with unit, AAU in the sequel) on $T(\mathfrak{g}_1)\otimes T(\mathfrak{g}_2)$ (call it $*$) such that $\rho$ is a morphism (of AAU), this law reads
$t_1*t_2:=\rho(j(t_1)\otimes j(t_2))$ and (we identify $t$ and $j(t)$)
$$
(t_1*t_2)*t_3=\rho(\rho(t_1\otimes t_2)\otimes t_3)=
\rho(t_1\otimes t_2\otimes t_3)=t_1*(t_2*t_3)
$$

then the kernel of $\rho$ is a two sided ideal which contains all the elements (with $(g_2,h_1)\in \mathfrak{g}_2\times \mathfrak{g}_1$)
$$
B(g_2,h_1)=g_2\otimes h_1 - h_1\otimes g_2 - [g_2,h_1]\ .
$$
By composition, we now have a linear morphism $\beta_0=(s_1\otimes s_2)\circ\rho$
$$
T(\mathfrak{g}) \stackrel{\rho}{\rightarrow} T(\mathfrak{g}_1)\otimes T(\mathfrak{g}_2)
\stackrel{s_1\otimes s_2}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1)\otimes\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_2)
$$
where $s_i$ is the canonical surjection $T(\mathfrak{g}_i)\to \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_i)$. Let us show now that the kernel of $s:T(\mathfrak{g})\to \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ is included in $ker(\beta_0)$, so that we could factorize $\beta_0$ through $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ as follows.
$$ 
\require{AMScd} 
\begin{CD}
T(\mathfrak{g}) @>{\rho}>>T(\mathfrak{g}_1)\otimes T(\mathfrak{g}_2)\\
@V{s}VV @VV{s_1\otimes s_2}V \\
\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}) @>{\beta}>> \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1)\otimes\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_2)
\end{CD} 
$$
Let us prove that this last diagram is admissible.

We know that $\mathcal{J}=ker(s)$ is the two sided ideal generated by the elements $\{B(g,h)\}_{g,h\in \mathfrak{g}}$ where
$$
B(g,h)=g\otimes h - h\otimes g - [g,h]
$$
As $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus\mathfrak{g}_2$ and $B(-,-)$ is bilinear antisymmetric it amounts to the same to split the family in three relators
$$
\{B(g_1,h_1)\}_{g_1,h_1\in \mathfrak{g}_1}\cup \{B(g_2,h_2)\}_{g_2,h_2\in \mathfrak{g}_2}\cup
\{B(g_2,h_1)\}_{(g_2,h_1)\in \mathfrak{g}_2\times \mathfrak{g}_1}
$$
Calling $\mathcal{J}_{ij}$ be the corresponding (two-sided) ideals, we have already shown that
$$
\mathcal{J}_{21}\subset ker(\rho)\subset ker(\beta_0)
$$
The fact that $\mathcal{J}_{11}\subset ker(\beta_0)$ is a consequence of the following identity (for $g_2\in \mathfrak{g}_2$ and $g_1,h_1\in \mathfrak{g}_1$)
$$
g_2\otimes B(g_1,h_1)\equiv_\rho B([g_2,g_1]_1,h_1)+B(g_1,[g_2,h_1]_1)+ B(g_1,h_1)\otimes g_2\qquad (*)
$$
where $\equiv_\rho$ means the equivalence modulo $ker(\rho)$.

One shows very similarly that $\mathcal{J}_{22}\subset ker(\beta_0)$, hence the square diagram above. Computing on generators shows that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are mutually inverse.

**Remarks** i) The same proof seems to show that, in case
$$
\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus \mathfrak{s} 
$$
where $\mathfrak{s}$ is some submodule, then the arrow
$$ 
\alpha\ :\ \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g_1})\otimes \mathcal{A}(\mathfrak{s})\to \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})
$$
(where $\mathcal{A}(\mathfrak{s})$ is the subalgebra generated by $\mathfrak{s}$) is one-to-one.

ii) Generalizing the straightening process to $|I|<+\infty$, and taking into account the ambiguities (squares and hexagons), it seems true that, for any decomposition
$$
\mathfrak{g}=\oplus_{i\in I}\, \mathfrak{g}_i 
$$
(equality is as $R$-modules but any individual $\mathfrak{g}_i$ is a Lie subalgebra), the ($I$ being linearly ordered) multiplication map (only linear)
$$
\stackrel{\rightarrow}{\otimes}_{i\in I}\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_i)
\stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}) 
$$
is one-to-one. However the construction and proofs seem considerably more difficult.

iii) If $I$ is infinite, one first constructs
$\stackrel{\rightarrow}{\otimes}_{i\in I}\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_i)$ as in Bourbaki Algebra Chapter III § 4.5 using the unities but **not** the algebra structure. We can, again, ask the same question.

Please do not hesitate to interact if something is wrong or unclear !

**Late edit** i) *Proof of identity* $(*)$.

Let us use two derivations within $T(\mathfrak{g})$ defined on the generators $g\in \mathfrak{g}$ by
$$
ad_{g_2}^{\otimes}(g):=g_2\otimes g-g\otimes g_2=[g_2,g]_{\otimes}
\ ;\ ad_{g_2}(g):=[g_2,g]
$$
then, for $g_2\in \mathfrak{g}_2$ and because, for $u\in\mathfrak{g}_1$,
$ad_{g_2}^{\otimes}(u)\equiv_\rho ad_{g_2}(u)$,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&& ad_{g_2}^{\otimes}(B(g_1,h_1))=ad_{g_2}^{\otimes}([g_1,h_1]_{\otimes}-[g_1,h_1])\cr
&&=[[g_2,g_1]_{\otimes},h_1]_{\otimes}+[g_1,[g_2,h_1]_{\otimes}]_{\otimes}-
ad_{g_2}^{\otimes}([g_1,h_1])\cr
&&\equiv_\rho [[g_2,g_1]_{\otimes},h_1]_{\otimes}+[g_1,[g_2,h_1]_{\otimes}]_{\otimes}-
ad_{g_2}([g_1,h_1])\cr
&&\equiv_\rho [[g_2,g_1],h_1]_{\otimes}+[g_1,[g_2,h_1]]_{\otimes}-
[[g_2,g_1],h_1]-[g_1,[g_2,h_1]]\cr
&&\equiv_\rho B([g_2,g_1],h_1)+B(g_1,[g_2,h_1])\cr
&&\equiv_\rho B([g_2,g_1]_1,h_1)+B(g_1,[g_2,h_1]_1)\cr
\end{eqnarray}
$$

ii) *Proof of $\mathcal{J}_{11}\subset ker(\beta_0)$*

The two-sided ideal $\mathcal{J}_{11}$ is linearly generated by the elements
$$
s=u_1\otimes B(g_1,h_1)\otimes u_2
$$
with $g_1,h_1\in \mathfrak{g}_1$ and $u_i\in T_{w_i}$

We first rewrite each $u_i$ with $\rho$ and get that the two-sided ideal $\mathcal{J}_{11}$ is linearly generated by elements of the form
$$
t\equiv_\rho t_1\otimes t_2 \otimes B(g_1,h_1)\otimes t_3\otimes t_4  
$$
with $t_1\in T_{a^p},\ t_2\in T_{b^q},\ t_3\in T_{a^r},\ t_4\in T_{b^s}$.

If $q>0$, we have $t_2=t'_2\otimes g_2$, for some $g_2\in \mathfrak{g}_2$

then using identity $(*)$ , one has
$$
t\equiv_\rho t_1\otimes t'_2 \otimes \Big(
B([g_2,g_1]_1,h_1)+B(g_1,[g_2,h_1]_1)+B(g_1,h_1)\otimes g_2\Big)\otimes t_3\otimes t_4
$$
using a recurrence on $q$, one gets
$$
t\equiv_\rho t_1\otimes \Big(\sum_{i=1}^{q} B(x_i,y_i)\otimes v_i\otimes t_3\otimes t_4\Big) 
$$
with $x_i,y_i\in \mathfrak{g}_1$ and $v_i$ in some $T_{w_i}$. Now
$$
t\equiv_\rho \Big(\sum_{i=1}^n t_1\otimes B(x_i,y_i)\otimes \rho(v_i\otimes t_3\otimes t_4)\Big) 
$$
applying $\beta_0$ (which is compatible with $\equiv_\rho$) to both members, we have
$$
\beta_0(t)=\beta_0\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n t_1\otimes B(x_i,y_i)\otimes \rho(v_i\otimes t_3\otimes t_4)\Big)=0 
$$

Comment: Why is the multiplication $*$ associative? Also, some extraneous $\in$ signs in the definition of $r_{w,i}$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg [Why is the multiplication ∗ associative]---> Good question, let me think of it (maybe my argument is incomplete). [$\in$ signs in the definition of $r_{w,i}$]---> this is to show in which sectors the result goes.

Comment: Let me know when you've fixed the associativity argument (or maybe you don't need it?). BTW: If you can show the analogous fact for an arbitrary direct sum (not just of $2$ submodules), then you'll have gotten a new proof of Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt (even one of the more general versions: the one where $\mathfrak{g}$ is assumed to be a direct sum of cyclic modules).

Comment: @darijgrinberg  I think  it is fixed, this is due to the rewriting process (I added property 4), thanks for interaction (+1)

Comment: This is looking better and better! But I don't quite see how you get $\mathcal{J}_{11} \subseteq \ker\beta_0$. Also, minor typo: one of the $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$s in the commutative diagram should be a $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1)$.

Comment: Also, it might be that you don't need the AAU structure any more, since the fact that $\ker \rho$ is an ideal follows straight from property 4. Unless you tacitly use it in the proof of $\mathcal{J}_{11} \subseteq \ker\beta_0$ (is $s_1 \otimes s_2$ an algebra homomorphism?).

Comment: @darijgrinberg [But I don't quite see how you get ...]---> One has $\ker(\rho)\subset \ker(\beta_0)$ then, due to the last identity $$\beta_0(u\otimes B(g_1,h_1)\otimes v)=\beta_0(u_1\otimes B(g_1,h_1)\otimes u_2)=0$$ where $u_i\in T(\mathfrak{g}_i)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78679/discussion-between-duchamp-gerard-h-e-and-darij-grinberg).

Comment: OK, I admit I don't understand how you prove the "last identity" either.